# Unity7 Launcher (dock) is white with black icons

Tags: unity, launcher

I changed the Launcher color in unity-tweak-tool, just to try it out, and changed it back to based on wallpaper and this happened. Don't know why or how it happened and now I need to fix it.

My first thought would be deleting the configuration files, but I can't find them. Here are some screenshots:

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Everything else works just fine.

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on a Raspberry Pi 4 B with 4GB RAM, with the inbuilt graphics and no proprietary drivers.